# Constraints in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

So, I have this exercise I'm trying to solve. I have a database and I need to add a constraint. I don't know if I solved it right because I'm new to this and I'm trying to teach myself, but after searching I concluded it might be by using a foreign key constraint.

These are the relevant tables for this question in my db:

```
MusicGroup(idG, name, city, country, year)

Edition(idG, titleE, year, editor)
idG : FK(MusicGroup)

Music(idG, titleM, length)
idG : FK(MusicGroup)

Album(idG, titleE)
idG, titleE : FK(Edition)

Track(idG, titleE, number, titleM)
idG, titleE : FK(Album)
idG, titleM : FK(Music)

Single(idG, titleE, titleM)
idG, titleE : FK(Edition)
idG, titleM : FK(Music)
```

Here are the instructions to create the database (also made by me):

```
create table MusicGroup (idG char(10) not null
    unique(idG),
    name varchar(255) not null,
    city varchar(255) not null,
    country varchar(255) not null,
    year numeric(6,0) not null,
    primary key (idG))


create table Edition (idG char(10) not null,
    titleE varchar(50) not null,
    year numeric(6,0) not null,
    editor varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (idG, titleE),
    foreign key(idG) references MusicGroup(idG))


create table Music (idG char(10) not null,
    titleM varchar(50) not null
    unique(titleM),
    length float(1) not null,
    primary key (idG, titleM),
    foreign key(idG) references MusicGroup(idG))


create table Album (idG char(10) not null,
    titleE varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (idG, titleE),
    foreign key(idG, titleE) references Edition(idG, titleE))


create table Track (idG char(10) not null,
    titleE varchar(50) not null,
    number smallint not null,
    titleM varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (idG, titleE, number),
    foreign key(idG, titleE) references Album(idG, titleE),
    foreign key(idG, titleM) references Music(idG, titleM))


create table Single (idG char(10) not null,
    titleE varchar(50) not null,
    titleM varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (idG, titleE),
    foreign key(idG, titleE) references Edition(idG, titleE),
    foreign key(idG, titleM) references Music(idG, titleM))
```

I have to add the following constraint: The title of an album must be the title of one of the tracks on that album, and that track must have been already published as single.

So I tried to solve this way:

```
alter table Album
add foreign key (idG, titleE, titleE) references Track(idG, titleE, titleM)

alter table Track
add foreign key (idG, titleE, titleM) references Single(idG, titleE, titleM)
```

I have to say that the first foreign key doesn't seem too good, but as I said, I'm new to this.

Thank you so much in advance for any help :)

Comment: I don't think I understand your notation(What is this idG field?). Could you please add the _real_ table definitions?

Comment: @wildplasser : These are the _real_ table definitions. The idG is an id for the group, an identification string, something like in an identity card of national citizen (just making a real comparison so you can understand better).

Comment: You have composite primary keys on all tables? I meant: if you add the actual "CREATE TABLE" statements for the stuff, that would save others than you a lot of (guess)work.

Comment: @wildplasser: I've added that information to my post, I hope it helps. But, as I wrote the solution, I don't know if it is completely correct :\

Answer (score 1):

With this set of table definitions, SQL FK's are not the way to go.  The target for the FK that you would need is a JOIN between Track and Single (to express the notion that album title must be known as a Track on that album AND must be known as a single).

There's no way to do this in SQL except by lowering the design's NF level and introduce redundancy (and even then I'm not so sure it would suffice in this particular case).

You say this is a book's exercise.  Did that book also cover CHECK constraints ?  If so, the aim of the exercise is probably to make you write an appropriate check constraint.  If not, I really can't imagine what kind of solution the author had in mind.

Note that while the SQL standard allows you to write almost anything in a CHECK constraint, many implementations offer only a very limited subset of the full "theoretical" functionality defined by the standard.

Comment: Yes it did cover **check** constraints. Would it be something like                                            

`alter table Album
add constraint titleAlbum_is_Track_in_Single
check (idG, titleE) in (select idG, titleM from Single)`

Comment: No, you would still have to specify the JOIN that says that some title is both a track title on the album concerned and a single title : something like CHECK (idG, titleE) IN ((SELECT idG, titleE FROM Track WHERE titleE=titleM) JOIN (SELECT idG,titleM) FROM Single WHERE ...).  Or like CHECK ... IN select_from_Track AND ... IN select_from_Single.  Or two distinct CHECK constraints that each express one part of the AND.  I'm not familiar enough with how they should be written to give you any kind of definite answer on this.

Comment: What I am quite certain about is that with any implementation, you'll have to defer constraint checking until you've done your inserts in both album and track : you cannot insert a track if there is no album for it, and under your constraint, you cannot insert an album unless there already is a track for it (namely the one that will make the album title valid).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a foreign key is the best way of asserting that constraint. I would definitely add a **trigger** for that.

Comment: I don't think that the author of the book intended the use of **triggers** as this is in the _Referential Constraints_ section and the next section is the one with _Triggers_ (I haven't reached that part yet) :\

But thank you so much for trying to help me.

Comment: I've started reading the triggers part and it got me interested in discovering how you would do this in triggers. What would you suggest as steps? It is a little bit confusing the trigger part.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you have to do is get a unique constraint you can reference, Since you allow duplicate titles for tracks on the cd, you are going to have to change this:

```
ALTER TABLE album ADD named_after_track int not null;

ALTER TABLE album 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (idG, titleE, titleE, named_after_track)
REFERENCES track (idg, titleE, titleM, number)
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Hope this helps.  Note the deferred key will be enforced at commit time since we won't know that this is valid until that point.

Answer (score -1):

First:

- i'd let every table have a single-field (non-composite) primary key. (this will cause the need for another constraint: an album or edition cannot contain fragments from multiple artists) I also feel a strong tencency to make these surrogate-ids numeric.
- you make the names unique for a lot of your entities. This will probably not hold ("greatest Hits")
- some naming: most people strongly advise against MixedCase in TableNames (it forces you to quote the identifiers every time and it is harder to read, it also might confuse DBMSes, which may or may not be case significant, depending on the phase of the moon)
- more naming: I'dd call track what you call Music
- I'd call artist what you call MusicGroups
- I'd rename Track to something like "tracklist" or "album_toc"  (or track_album_relation).
- (maybe) I'd combine single and album into one entity ("zrecord"), and add a type-tag, this would also allow for singles to have flipsides, allow for EP's, etc.
- I don't know what the purpose of Edition is. You might even need a similar mechanism ("versions", remasterings") for the individual tracks.

... more to follow.

Comment: -1.  The question is about a constraint, but you don't address that at all.

Comment: Well: the real underlying issue is "constraint minimalisation": a good data design should have the minimal amount (and complexity) of constraints. (and I really don't understand why I am getting voted down, while you are basically saying the same or less, but I don't care about votes.) Besides: this is homework.

Comment: @wildplasser: I think you are right but the tables were already described in the exercise, as I wrote them, it wasn't a text where  I should discover what should be created. And I have to tell you it is not homework since I don't have classes for this. I told I'm learning studying by myself. Besides, if I were in a class of this it would be much easier to ask the teacher about my doubts. Thank you for trying to help me.